# Assign value to inline Javascript using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to load a canvas to calculate the profile meter for user. I calculated the the value and assigned it to a angular scope variable. My canvas code is in the inline javascript. How can I assign the value to the variable in inline javascript?

here's the code to the Canvas and my jade file:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
  var al= document.getElementById('my_canvas').value;
  var start = 4.72;
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height; 
  var diff;
  function progressSim(){
    diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI*2*10).toFixed(2);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(al+'%', cw*.5, ch*.5+2, cw);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, start, diff/10+start, false);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  progressSim();
```

```html
<!-- canvas(id="my_canvas" width="70" height="70") -->
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="70" height="70" />
```

and also is there a better approach to do this?

here's the working Plunker ! 
https://plnkr.co/edit/5qKZ9fGY1miinouWC7Iy

Comment: please make plunker

Comment: I have updated the plunker. Please see !!

Comment: You want value `70` to be assigned instead of `al = 50`?

Comment: yes !! I want to assign the value of scope variable instead of 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove inline code and add it in app.js and Please find the changes `$scope.canvas` instead of `al`

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.canvas = 70;
  var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
  var start = 4.72;
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height; 
  var diff;
  function progressSim(){
    diff = (($scope.canvas / 100) * Math.PI*2*10).toFixed(2);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText($scope.canvas+'%', cw*.5, ch*.5+2, cw);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, start, diff/10+start, false);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  progressSim();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you using a `hidden` input. This way you can set its value and then access it in `progressSim`

Few pointers:

- Value from DOM element is string so you will manually have to parse it to number.
- You should define `af` inside `progressSim` as you are expecting its value to change.
- `.value || 0` is a safeguard if value is missing or removed. It should not show `undefined%`.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
var start = 4.72;
var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
var diff;

function progressSim() {
  var al = +(document.getElementById('myValue').value || 0);
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();
}
progressSim();


document.getElementById("btnUpdate").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('myValue').value = +(document.getElementById('myValue').value || 0) + 10;
  progressSim();
})
```

```html
<!-- canvas(id="my_canvas" width="70" height="70") -->
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="70" height="70"></canvas>
<input type="hidden" id="myValue" value="10" />

<button id="btnUpdate">Update value by 10</button>
```

Comment: this is  a backwards approach in an angular app

Comment: @charlietfl My apologies if this is a bad approach

Comment: in angular would pass value from controller to the dom and wrap all this code in a directive